# Try or Install Ubuntu is not working on Asus G14

Tags: boot, 23.04

I'm currently on the 22.04 distro and trying to do a reinstallation with 23.04. I do have Windows on dual boot. However, after pressing `try or install ubuntu` my prompt immediately stops/freezes executing on `amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device`. I have been using ubuntu on this machine for more than a year now and I have never faced anything like this prior to this.

NB: I do have fastboot and secure boot disabled.

[image]

Comment: You weren't very specific with details; eg. you mention Ubuntu & release details (22.04 & 23.04) but not which product (eg. Server? or Desktop?) nor which installer/ISO you used if it's a desktop system (Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop has two ISO choices using two different installers and if it's desktop you're asking about; you've not said which).  Please clarify with specifics.  You've also not ruled out *procedural* type issues such as ISO validation & writing of ISO to media correctly, esp. given 23.04's size if it's desktop this is very important.

Comment: I would stay on 22.04, as it is a LTS version.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Let's try with some diagnostics to help with troubleshooting. Can you please edit your question to include the output of `dmesg` (looking for amdgpu, `sudo dmesg | grep -i amdgpu`)? Fingers crossed.

Comment: 23.04, with latest kernel. It freeze for amdgpu.

Comment: @omar did you figure it out? I am having the same issue

Comment: @KhayamGondal Nope, I couldn’t. It seems that it’s kernel issue, so went ahead with 22.04 then upgraded it to 23.

Answer (score 0):

This is a driver issue. Try booting into safe/rescue mode and installing Ubuntu. Once installed, choose rescue mode and install Nvidia drivers using the ubuntu-drivers command and reboot.